# Is there a way to vectorize the use of squeeze in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am currently using `squeeze` to remove two singleton dimensions from a matrix. The matrix is a large 4d matrix `M(:,:,:,:)`. The first two dimensions are row and column coordinates (`y` and `x`). The variable in the third dimension (`indexes`) selects several values in the third dimension of `M`.

In a for-loop i am running, matrix `M` is adressed as `M(y,x,indexes,:)`, which makes the first two dimensions singleton dimensions. These dimensions are then removed with `squeeze` for use in `pdist`, like so:

```
pdist(squeeze(M(y,x,indexes,:)))
```

Can i vectorize the use of `squeeze` in this case? (It takes up a lot of time in the loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If matrix `M` is not changed inside the loop, a simple solution is to reorder the matrix dimensions with [PERMUTE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/permute.html) before running for-loop:

```
Mperm = permute(M,[3 4 1 2]);
```

Then you can address `Mperm` instead of `M` as `Mperm(:,:,y,x)`.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to remove the singleton dimensions, not reorder them. With your solution, i am still left with a matrix with two singleton dimensions, only in a different order. Or am i misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: You will not have to remove singleton dimensions, since if x and y are scalars, after indexing you will get 2D matrix, not 4D.

Comment: Ok, I see. One more question: since M is a rather large matrix, will permute not process the *entire* matrix on each call and slow things down rather than speed them up (since it is used in a for-loop)?

Comment: I'm saying run permute only once **before** for loop. Then in the loop just `pdist(Mperm(:,:,y,x))`. Does `M` get changed inside the loop?

Comment: No, but the loop goes through every y and x coordinate of `M`. So i would have to let it create y*x permutations of matrix `M`.

Comment: @samuel Just try it out... permute once, then loop as you currently do, but without squeeze.  The looping will take care of all x and y, you don't have to permute differently for each combination of those indices.

Comment: Ah, it works perfectly (and sped the whole process up by 23%). Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

For this type of problem using `reshape` is often a massive improvement on squeeze. I had a issue where squeeze was taking about half the time it took to run a function. Using the profiler I could see squeeze doing a number of unnecessary checks. Using reshape reduced the time for the same operation to 15% of the original time required.